# Replace values in column with matching column in different DF

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have two data frames:

```
DF <- data.frame(A=letters[1:5],B=1:5) 
DF_2 <- data.frame(match_col = c("a","a","c"))
```

Here we have to get only matching columns of `DF_2$match_col`

```
final_df <- data.frame(A=c("a","a","c","d","e"),B=1:5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question here is not very clear. For youR DF_2, I am not sure if there is a column of B in it. I assume you forgot to include it, as I assume you need that column to perform matching.

Please see below:

```
DF <- data.frame(A=letters[1:5],B=1:5) 
DF_2 <- data.frame(match_col = c("a","a","c"))
DF_2$B=c(1:3)
DF$A= as.character(DF$A)
DF_2$match_col= as.character(DF_2$match_col)
for(id in 1:nrow(DF_2)){
  DF$A[DF$B %in% DF_2$B[id]] <- DF_2$match_col[id]
}

DF
```

Here my DF matches with your final_df, therefore I presume my assumption is right.